# Set color (or other properties) of UIView in xib file PER TARGET

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, xib

I am working on a few different apps that reuse the same xib file, but each app has it's own color scheme.

For most parts of the app (Nav bar color, `UIBarButtonItem`'s), we use the `UIAppearance` method for each app.

For some parts, however, it becomes more complicated, such as the color of a labels need to be color A, B, and C for App 1, and need to be Color B, C, and D for App 2, and I cannot think of an easy way of doing this with `UIAppearance`.

An obvious, hard way of doing this would be somewhere when the view controller loads to set the colors of the label there, and have the colors stored in a plist or something similar. Also I could duplicate the xib for each project and edit the colors in the xib, but it defeats the purpose of sharing the xibs and I would have to be constantly updating multiple xibs for each change to the UI.

I am curious, however, if I could use the "`User Defined Runtime Attributes`" or something else that will be easy to manager in order to tackle this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yet again a feature xcode doesn't offer. I'm crying so much after developing Android. Everything is handled in code whilst it should be in UIbuilder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make two Targets named

redColor
blueColor

in both of it , Goto Build Settings > set Pre Processor macros >

for redColor > add Preprocessor Macro IS_RED_THEME
for blueColor> add Preprocessor Macro IS_BLUE_THEME

Now in your Class

in viewWillAppear or in viewDidLoad or anywhere you want put this code :

```
#ifdef IS_RED_THEME
//apply Red COlor
#elif IS_BLUE_THEME
//apply Blue Color
#endIf
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use Other C Flags they bagan with -D

like -DIS_RED_THEME

Answer (score 1):

For my opinion, I created a class named "Palette", and in this class, I created some constant colors. At the starting of my application, I initiate this class (only one time), and I can have access to all colors I want in my app. Here an example:

**Palette.h**:

```
/* HEXA to RGB */
#define UIColorFromRGB(hexValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((hexValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((hexValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(hexValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]


/* Used colors in app */
#define kColor1         UIColorFromRGB(0xFFFFFF)
#define kColor2         UIColorFromRGB(0x48CF35)


@interface Palette : NSObject

+ (Palette *)shared;

#pragma mark - Colors
@property (nonatomic, readonly)UIColor *color1;
@property (nonatomic, readonly)UIColor *color2;
```

And my **Palette.m**:

```
@implementation Palette
{
    UIColor *color1;
    UIColor *color2;
}

+ (Palette *)shared
{
    static Palette *instance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[Palette alloc] init];
    });

    return instance;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        //...
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Colors
- (UIColor *)color1
{
    if(nil == color1)
        color1 = kColor1;
    return color1;
}

- (UIColor *)color2
{
    if(nil == color2)
        color2 = kColor2;
    return color2;
}
```

Next, I add the Pallete.h class in my app-Prefix.pch file to have access anywhere.
Finally, in my app delegate when appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I called simply:

```
[Palette shared];
```

And to add color for a UILabel:

```
UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
        [label setText:@"My label"];
        [label setTextColor:[[Palette shared] color1]];
```

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

so we got 2 possible solutions already:

1. Singleton containing colors by Lapinou
2. Preprocessor Macros by Xeieshan

I can think of 3 additional ones:

1. NSUserdefaults (working as the singleton does)
   You can set up all the colors in the NSUserDefaults as runonce and load those in every controller.
   You can either archive the colors into NSData and load them directly or load a hex string and create it when you need it.
2. Create an object at start holding all the colors (ButtonPrimary, ButtonSecondary etc...like the singleton) and pass it through your navigation.
3. Add a category to NSObject containing all the colors. They should be available everywhere now.

I can't say much performance wise, but i think the singleton suggested by Lapinou will do its job. Just be sure to name those propertys accordingly (LabelTextPrimary, LabelBorderFine, LabelBorderThick and so on) as color1, color2, color3 will break your neck pretty soon.

On a personal note, i am using 1+2 (my list) as i can freely choose to use the global(nsuserdefault) colorscheme while let a significant navigationcontroller use its own.

If you want to go with NSUserDefaults this may help.

```
- (UIColor *) createColorFromHex:(NSString *)hexString  
{
    NSString *cleanString = [hexString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];
    if([cleanString length] == 3) {
        cleanString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@",
                       [cleanString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)],[cleanString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)],
                       [cleanString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1)],[cleanString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1)],
                       [cleanString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 1)],[cleanString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 1)]];
    }
    if([cleanString length] == 6) {
        cleanString = [cleanString stringByAppendingString:@"ff"];
    }

    unsigned int baseValue;
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:cleanString] scanHexInt:&baseValue];

    float red = ((baseValue >> 24) & 0xFF)/255.0f;
    float green = ((baseValue >> 16) & 0xFF)/255.0f;
    float blue = ((baseValue >> 8) & 0xFF)/255.0f;
    float alpha = ((baseValue >> 0) & 0xFF)/255.0f;

    // NSLog(@"SUCCESS; Color created: %f, %f, %f, %f from %@",red,green,blue,alpha,cleanString);

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
}
```

EDIT: stackoverflow is messing up my numbers :D